# Create extended desktop with two external monitors on laptop on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I'm on a Dell Latitude D620.

I have two external monitors, one at 1920x1080 and the other at 1680x1050.

*What do I need to display an extended desktop across these two external monitors?* It's fine to leave the laptop screen blank. Is a VGA splitter sufficient or do I need a second video card?

Answer (score 1):

Check out UV plus displaylink adapter.

[image]

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815101006

I have a UV12 (which will power up to 1440x900), and it works great! I can edit normal office related documents, write code, surf Internet. I can also play YouTube video without any problem. If you don't do 3D gaming, this is a little device for you.

Comment: Gave you a point for this suggestion. I recently got a USB speaker to counter my laptop's M.I.A.-happy integrated sound (Toshiba U305 S107). Yet I never even thought that USB add-on video-cards existed. It would be better in VGA-native style, but us beggars can't be choosers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an additional video card or a laptop dock that has multiple VGA outputs.  You can get a USB dock that has VGA outputs, or a USB Display Adapter, but those have very poor performance in my experience.  If you have a PC Card or PC Card Express slot you would be further along to use one of those, but performance would still not be fantastic.

A VGA splitter will merely copy the signal.